# ul is not occupying the full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Do you know why the list items are not occupying the full width (have some white margin)? And also why the right arrow is not position at right using `justify-content: space-between`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lph010v6/

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="MobileCategories">
        <li>
          <div>
            <img src="/img/categories/category1.svg"/>
            <span class="MobileCategories__title">Category</span>
          </div>
          <span><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <a href=""> </a>
        </li>
         <li>
          <div>
            <img src="/img/categories/category2.svg"/>
            <span class="MobileCategories__title">Category 2</span>
          </div>
          <span><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <a href=""> </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.MobileCategories{
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:green;
  li{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: orange;
    padding:20px;

    img{
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .MobileCategories__title{

      margin-left: 15px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know why the list items are not occupying the full width (have
>   some white margin)?

The `container-fluid` has some *default* padding - reset this to 0 (if so desired)

> And also why the right arrow is not position at right using
>   justify-content-between.

Note that you have an empty `a` tag inside the `li` that is preventing the `justify-content: space-between`.

See demo below:

```css
/*This style from normalize styles of jsfiddle*/
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container-fluid { /*ADDED THIS*/
  padding: 0!important;
}

.MobileCategories {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.MobileCategories li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px;
}

.MobileCategories li img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.MobileCategories li .MobileCategories__title {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="MobileCategories">
        <li>
          <div>
            <img src="/img/categories/category1.svg" />
            <span class="MobileCategories__title">Category</span>
          </div>
          <span><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <!--<a href=""> </a>-->
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <img src="/img/categories/category2.svg" />
            <span class="MobileCategories__title">Category 2</span>
          </div>
          <span><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <!--<a href=""> </a>-->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `li` elements are taking up the full width in your Fiddle. You have padding on your `container-fluid` element that is adding padding - set this to 0 and it will remove it.

   ```
   .container-fluid { padding-left:0; padding:right:0; }
   ```
2. The arrow is not being positioned to the right because it is not the right-most element. You have an `<a>` element after it, and it is getting positioned to the right - you just can't see it because it's empty.

   ```
   <li>
     <div>[...]</div>
     <span>[..]</span>
     <a href=""> </a> /* this is the element being positioned to the right*/
   </li>
   ```